# Access(SQL) splitting two fields in one data into two data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a aet of data like this.

__________Port__ %_____ Port(2)___       %(2)

NameA              620         5%            640           3%

(Port, %, port(2), %(2) are fields name)

But I want to split this data into like that in MS Access:

Port#            %

NameA        620         5%

NameA        640         3%

In other words, I want to split fields above into two and make two entries or two separate data.
Is there anyway I can do in MS Access?
I am using MS Access 2010

Thank you and have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

create an append query into the table itself. Port(2), %(2) to be appended into Port, %. Then you can delete the two extra columns.